# Add a picture in screen while user open camera for taking picture

Tags: java, android, camera

I want to make application like this . I want when user open the camera and want to take a picture . Suddenly After period of time one image (like a ghost image ) appear on the screen and finally can take photo with this picture .
I search but nothing find. if you have any suggestion to how start this project or any helping links?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a custom camera in your app then you will be able to add an image after the certain time of period

Comment: did you understand?

Comment: is there any example or piece of code to make more clarify?@PratikSatani

Comment: Yes. for example https://github.com/google/cameraview 
This is one example of a custom camera. You can add any images on the camera surface.

Comment: thnx@PratikSatani

Comment: If I will add this reply as an answer then would you please accept it?

Comment: whould you plaease help how to add the image . ? It is more difficult source@PratikSatani

Comment: Check this link :https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141
these all are custom camera libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a custom camera in your app then you will be able to add an image after the certain time of period

for example [Custome Camera](http://github.com/google/cameraview) This is one example of a custom camera. You can add any images on the camera surface

Happy Coding...